# Why do operators send $L^p \rightarrow L^q$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I've seen that operators on $L^p$ space often have codomain $L^q$ for $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Why is this true? And under what assumptions? (Linear?)

For example, the kernel operator :
$$ Tu(x) = \int_0^1 K(x,y) u(y)dy , \;\;\; u\in L^p[0,1].$$

Why is $Tu\in L^q[0,1]$? Is this even true?

Comment: This depends very much on what properties $K$ has. But, once sufficient conditions on $K$ are introduced, it often boils down to Holder's inequality.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks. would the Holder's inequality here be something like $\|u Tu \|_1 \leq \|u\|_p  \|Tu\|_q $ ? Does $\|uTu \|_1$ have to be finite for some reason?

Comment: It really depends on the known properties of $K$, and for more precise results, you should look them up in whatever textbook/notes you're following. For example, if $K$ is bounded, then $T$ maps $L^1$ to $L^{\infty}$, and $\|Tu\|_{\infty}\leq \|K\|_{\infty}\|u\|_1$.

Comment: For instance, see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_integral_operators